# Implementations of spring/electrostatic drawing for graphs with specified edge lengths

Tags: algorithm, graph, wolfram-mathematica

Suppose I have some non-planar graph $G$ with fully specified edge lengths $(r_1,...,r_N) \in R$, but where I do not have specified coordinates for the vertices.  I want to draw $G$ on a two dimensional surface by specifying the edges as springs of some length, having electrostatic repulsion between the vertices, and then doing something akin to simulated annealing.

Mathematica seems to have functionality for all of the above, but it doesn't let you specify edge lengths.  Is there any software, in the public domain or not, that does all of this?  I've tried Tulip and GraphViz.  Tulip simply doesn't let you specify edge lengths, and Graphviz has very limited functionality in terms of specifying edge lengths and setting any sort of parameters for the simulated annealing step.

Update - I happen to know ahead of time that my particular set of edge lengths work!  The graph was previously drawn on a two-dimensional plain, but I don't have access to the coordinates.

I suppose I'm really looking for a package that can simulate a two-dimensional network of balls and springs.  Molecular dynamics software can do this, but the overhead there is enormous...

Comment: @belisarius how many tags to you watch?!

Comment: @belisarius: This is not a question on mma. The OP is only acknowledging mma in passing and asking if there is a similar software.

Comment: @yoda, true, but if someone has an idea for an implementation in Mathematica, I'd love to hear it!

Answer (score 3):

Like Mark said, it won't be always possible to do what you want. However, I would suggest trying [LevelScheme](http://wnsl.physics.yale.edu/levelscheme/) to draw squiggly arrows which look like springs. Here's an example:

```
<< "LevelScheme`"
pts = {{{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{0, 0}, {1, 1}}, {{1, 1}, {2, 0}}, {{2, 
     0}, {1, -1}}, {{1, -1}, {0, 0}}, {{0, 0}, {2, 0}}};
Figure[{
  SetOptions[SchemeArrow, ArrowType -> SquiggleArrow],
  SchemeArrow @@@ pts
  },
 PlotRange -> {{-0.1, 2.1}, {-1.1, 1.1}}
 ]
```

[image]

You can then embellish this by changing the wavelength of the arrows individually, which could represent different tension in the springs and add little disks that represent the vertices, etc. This is a bastardization of the level scheme diagrams in nuclear physics, but I guess is close to what you want.

Comment: This doesn't fully answer your question because you need to provide explicit points, and can't simply specify edge lengths. It was just a suggestion that you could look into, if you haven't already.

Answer (score 2):

There's no reason to expect to be able to do this. You can't place 4 points all distance one apart in the plane, for example.

Comment: The edges are springs and so their lengths are not fixed. Your goal is to lay out the graph in a way that minimizes total tension in all the springs.

Comment: @Mark could you translate "all distance one apart" into my two years old English, please?

Comment: @Igor Well, yes, that's the idea in a so called Spring Electrical Embedding. That's certainly not what the original poster indicated, however.

Comment: @belisarius: 3 points in a plane can be placed equidistant to each other (equilateral triangle). If you have 4 points, one point _has_ to be non-planar and the resulting polyhedron is a tetrahedron

Comment: @Belisarius I mean that the complete graph on 4 vertices, as returned by `CompleteGraph[4]` in Mathematica 8 for example, cannot be embedded in the plane in such a way that all edges have length 1. When the OP writes that he wants "fully specified edge lengths", it seems that he expects to be able to do that, but it's simply not possible.  Perhaps, he meant something else?

Comment: @Mark Oh, thanks. I didn't understand you because I think the OP is thinking in different lengths for each edge. In this case it is possible to find such arrangement

Comment: @Belisarius As I read it, it states that he wants to specify an arbitrary collection of lengths, which includes the possibility that they are all the same.  Given a large number of vertices and edge lengths, it will generally be unlikely that a graph with those specific edge lengths could be embedded in a low dimensional space.

Comment: @Mark Ok. There are two possible interpretations:1) For any set of springs lengths (at rest) find a compatible configuration [and you're right in this case] or 2) with a "correct" set of springs lengths, find the configuration. I understood the later.

Comment: @Mark, for this particular application, I happen to know that my particular set of edge-lengths work, i.e. the graph was previously drawn on a 2D plain with the specified lengths, but coordinate information was lost.  I'm not sure where the "all-distance-one" constraint is coming from?

Comment: @user The "all-distance-one" constraint isn't coming from anywhere.  It's just simplest example illustrating that you can't always specify edge lengths.  I've just posted another answer with code that supposes you have some apriori reason to believe that a certain set of edge lengths might work.  Perhaps this will help.

Answer (score 1):

OK, the discussion surrounding my previous answer makes it clear that the OP has edge lengths that work.  In this case, the problem can be specified algebraically and then solved.  Here's one approach to doing that.  Of course, it's always good to have a specific example stated in the question.  Lacking that, we can generate the essentials of the example.

Here's a random graph with 10 vertices and 20 edges.

```
SeedRandom[1];
g = RandomGraph[{10, 20}];
```

Let's draw it and extract out the vertex location information.  Thus, we will know lengths that work.

```
pic = GraphPlot[g];
pts = pic[[1, 1, 1]];
```

For any configuration with those lengths, the following expression will be zero.

```
length[UndirectedEdge[u_, v_]] := 
  Norm[pts[[u]] - pts[[v]]];
expr = Sum[((x[e[[1]]] - x[e[[2]]])^2 +
  (y[e[[1]]] - y[e[[2]]])^2 -
  length[e]^2)^2, {e, EdgeList[g]}];
```

Unfortunately, the expression is quite hard to minimize.  Let's suppose that we have inexact estimates of the original vertex locations.  (Perhaps this is possible, perhaps not.)  We could simulate this like so.  Note that we are simply randomly perturbing the original picture.

```
vars = Flatten[Table[{
   {x[i], pts[[i, 1]] + RandomReal[{-0.4, 0.4}]},
   {y[i], pts[[i, 2]] + RandomReal[{-0.4, 0.4}]}},
  {i, 1, 10}], 1];
```

Now, the following should yield vertex locations that work.

```
FindMinimum[expr, vars]
```

Comment: this is hitting very close to the minimization I'm currently trying, and it's very expensive for large graphs.  But I like your suggestion and I'll give it a shot!

Answer (score 0):

Maybe [tulip](http://tulip.labri.fr/TulipDrupal/) does what you want?

Answer (score 0):

You could also try to implement it yourself. It's not that hard and a lot of fun. "Simulated annealing" in this case is simply applying electrostatic physics with friction.

**The key point** is to use a Kd-Tree or an Octree to limit the complexity of the simulation. Otherwise O(n²) complexity will defeat you :)